# HTML/JavaScript project in AppCode IDE

Tags: javascript, html, css, appcode

Is it possible to create a web project (HTML, JavaScript, CSS) in Jetbrains AppCode IDE?

On the [Features](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/#more_than_objective-c_ide) page there is following information:

> AppCode also fully supports JavaScript, XML, HTML, CSS and XPath including all code editing and transformation features like syntax highlighting, analysis, completion, navigation and refactoring.

However I see only iOS and OS X when I use *File > New Project...* in AppCode 2.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) is an Objective-C IDE.  It supports web *code*, for they are frequently embedded in apps, but not pure web *project*.

You can either use [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), or open a dummy iOS project and disregard non-web parts.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create **Empty Project** ? And then fill it static resources.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is from IntelliJ IDEA and not from AppCode.

Comment: @devmake In AppCode doesn't have feature as `Create Empty Project` ?

Comment: @devmake Create empty folder in you computer and then try to import it to AppCode

Comment: It is possible to create empty project under iOS section and then use Add files... to add a folder for example. I tried it after Sheepy provided his answer. I just don't think that a screenshot from different app tells more than what you have already written.

Comment: @devmake Okey! Good luck